# Xamarin ios share extension get image

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, share-extension

I created demo application with Xamarin.Forms (5.X.X)

And i created share extension. Everything is good until here.

I want to get image from share extension but i cant get.

I tried almost everything.

```
public class CustomShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController
{
  

    public CustomShareViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }


    public override async void ViewDidLoad()
    {
         base.ViewDidLoad();

        string urlstr = string.Empty;

        NSExtensionItem item = ExtensionContext.InputItems[0];
        var itemProvider = item.Attachments[0];


        var type = itemProvider.Description.Split('"');
        if (itemProvider.HasItemConformingTo(type[1]))
        {

            var load = await itemProvider.LoadItemAsync(type[1], null);

            NSUrl newUrl = (NSUrl)load;
            urlstr = newUrl.FilePathUrl.ToString();

        }

        if (!Xamarin.Forms.Forms.IsInitialized)
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();



        // Create an instance of XF page with associated View Model
        var xfPage = new ShareMainPage();
        var viewModel = (ShareMainPageViewModel)xfPage.BindingContext;
        viewModel.Message = urlstr;
        viewModel.Image = urlstr;
        //viewModel.BindableImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
        // Override the behavior to complete the execution of the Extension when a user press the button
        viewModel.DoCommand = new Command(() => DoneClicked());
        // Convert XF page to a native UIViewController which can be consumed by the iOS Extension
        var newController = xfPage.CreateViewController();
        // Make sure the presentation style is set to full screen to avoid rendering the original entry point
        newController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
        // Present new view controller as a regular view controller
        this.PresentModalViewController(newController, false);

        //var someController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SomeController") as SomeViewController;
        //NavigationController.PushViewController(someController, true);

        //var itemProvider = inputItem?.Attachments?[0] as NSItemProvider;
        //if (itemProvider.HasItemConformingTo("public.url"))
        //{
        //    itemProvider.LoadPreviewImage(null, (item, error) => {

        //        if (item is UIImage)
        //        {
        //            var image = item as UIImage;
        //            var data = image.AsPNG();

        //            ImageView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);


        //        }

        //    });
        //}

    }

    public override bool ShouldInteractWithUrl(UITextView textView, NSUrl url, NSRange characterRange, UITextItemInteraction interaction)
    {
        return base.ShouldInteractWithUrl(textView, url, characterRange, interaction);
    }

    public override bool IsContentValid()
    {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return true;
    }

    public override void DidSelectPost()
    {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
    }

    public override void PresentationAnimationDidFinish()
    {
        base.PresentationAnimationDidFinish();
    }

  

    private void DoneClicked()
    {
        // Return any edited content to the host app.
        // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed-in items.
        ExtensionContext.CompleteRequest(ExtensionContext.InputItems, null);
    }

    private void WriteToDebugFile(string dbgText)
    {
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "Share-Extension-Debug.txt");

        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filename, $"\n{DateTime.Now} - {dbgText}");
        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(filename, $"\n{DateTime.Now} - {dbgText}");
        }
    }

}
```

I tried two ways.

1. Bind file path and get from there. ImageResource.FromFile(...) but it doesnt work.
2. Bind stream and it doesnt work too.

My sharepage.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModels"
 x:DataType="local:ShareMainPageViewModel"
  xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:LifeApp.Mobile.Converters"
BackgroundColor="Green"
x:Class="LifeApp.Mobile.Views.ShareMainPage">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ShareMainPageViewModel Message="Hello from Xamarin.Forms!" />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
  
        <Image Source="{Binding BindableImage}"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="150"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Message}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding DoCommand}" Text="Do the jungle!" TextColor="Black" />
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And SharePageViewModel

```
    using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Shapes;

namespace Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class ShareMainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            if (_message != value)
            {
                _message = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Message)));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _image;
    public string Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            if (_image != value)
            {
                _image = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));
            }
        }
    }


    public ImageSource _bindableImage { get; set; }


    public ImageSource BindableImage
    {
        get
        {
            return _bindableImage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_bindableImage !=null)
            {
            
                _bindableImage = value;

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BindableImage)));

            }
        }
    }

    private ICommand _doCommand;
    public ICommand DoCommand
    {
        get { return _doCommand; }
        set
        {
            if (_doCommand != value)
            {
                _doCommand = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DoCommand)));
            }
        }
    }

    public ShareMainPageViewModel()
    {
        DoCommand = new Command(OnDoCommandExecuted);
    }

    private void OnDoCommandExecuted(object state)
    {
      //  Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Completed");
        Message = $"Job {Environment.TickCount} has been completed!";
    }
}
}
```

I can get image file path but i cant bind and show image

file:///Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/58453DF3-58CF-4591-AC91-6A096FD7B814/data/Containers/Data/Application/1466F475-0F58-4F94-8511-B0BD9FE86DCA/tmp/WKFileShare-FbFp8eSD/adcf0796-2088-4d85-9420-c1d58c15cca4/....JPG

How can i solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: When you load it from, you can try to use the image.LoadFromURL(new NSUrl(filename, false)).

Comment: Im sorry but not working

Comment: Did you have the setting for the image share extension in the Info.plist?

Comment: yes i added setting

Comment: I can just get information about the DebugFile according to the code you provided. Could you please show the code about saving the image? The front part of the path will change  when you build the project in the simulator. Did you use an absolute path to load the image? And you can try to test it on the physical device to check if the error will appear or not.

Comment: You can check [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/600069/i-am-trying-to-update-a-database-entry-with-mixed.html) which has the similar problem. And I suggest you use the file path such as  `var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, photo.FileName);` For more information, you can check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/614155/i-am-trying-to-copy-a-library-image-to-a-persisten.html).

Comment: I fixed. Thank you for your help. Here is my solution: 
` var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(urlstr.Remove(0,7)); `
I removed first 7 character because it starts "file://" 
then i put byte array in to memory stream ` new MemoryStream(byteArray); `